# ffMpeg recording one input into 2 files with one encoder process

Tags: ffmpeg

need some help after trying days on this. I'm able to process one input to two outputs with two encodings:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 50000k -vf "scale=1920:1080" -an -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format mxf -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 50000k "C:\ffmpeg\Master\Master_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mxf" -b:v 50000k -vf "scale=1920:1080" -an -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_wrap 3 -segment_format mxf -reset_timestamps 1 -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 50000k "C:\ffmpeg\Backup\backup_%02d.mxf"
```

But when i try to do something to get rid of the second encoding and working with "tee" filter, i run into the problem that the other filters will not work anymore. If i run this without the extra filters:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" -c:v mpeg2video -an -f tee -map 0:v -an "Main.mxf|[f=mxf]Backup.mxf"
```

This works but trying to add this filters after the -f tee filter will lead into an error. As well to define this before the tee filter will not work due to different filter settings in segmentation.

I think the way how it could work is to split the output and use afterwards the tee filter. But i wasn't able to do. Maybe someone could help me here.

Best

Francois

Comment: How did you add the extra filters in tee.